# ionic/angular refresh like count with interval?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

HI I'm building out a basic social media site with ionic and am tracking the like counts for each post.  On page load I successfully show the like count that is in the db for each record.

```
$scope.getNewData = function () {
  $scope.page = 1;

  // get generic feed
  FeedService.getFeed(1)
  .then(function (data) {
      //We will update this value in every request because new posts can be created
     // console.log(data.totalPages)
      $scope.totalPages = data.totalPages;
      $scope.cards = data.posts;
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

      return "loaded new data";
  })
  .then(function (data) {

      //$rootScope.$broadcast('newDataLoaded');

  })

   $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

Issue is after the page loads and another user likes the record I want the like count to automatically update for all users.  I started playing around with `$interval` which works but the whole `$scope` changes , almost looks like a page refresh.  How can I only update the `$scope.cards.Post_Likes_Count` without having to refresh the entire `$scope.cards`?

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="actions-brief">
      <a href="#" class="subdued" id="{{card.PostID}}">{{card.Post_Likes_Count}} Likes</a>
      <a ng-controller="CommentsCtrl" ng-click="showComments(card)" class="subdued">{{card.comments}} Comments</a>
      <!--<a href="#" class="subdued">{{card.shares}} Shares</a>-->
    </div>
```

Ideally I would just want to refresh the `$scope.cards.Post_Likes_Count`.  Not sure how to keep everything in sync if I don't use `$scope.cards`.  I show 10 posts per page but as the user scrolls I grab 10 more records.

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole $scope should not change ... According to best practices, you should make the `$http` call in factory or service. Lets say you made an `http` call to your server to update the **like** done by your one user... You should call `activate()` function..

Activate function should be a user defined function which makes a request to the server while loading the page to get all the data from database and reload the $scope.yourData variable with latest data.

Moreover you should call the same `activate()` function from your controller using `$interval`. This would make your code more structured and proper.

And moreover you  should push data in your $scope.YOURDATA variable in your `activate()` function rather than assigning it each time...